# Convert a delimited string to JSON object with set of keys and values from the string

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, typescript

I have a string like this

```
var string = "1234|Tom|NYC|Student|Active"
```

and I want to map to something like in typescript NodeJS API

```
{  
  "Id": 1234,
  "Name": "Tom",
  "City": "NYC",
  "Title": "Student",
  "Status": "Active",
}
```

Here the key comes from a static set of keys that can be stored anywhere.

I tried converting string to array and tried `.reduce`, but I end up cannot get the desired results...
Can you please help out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have an array of the keys like below:

```
let keys = ["Id", "Name", "City", "Title", "Status"];
```

Then split the string on the delimiter as follows:

```
let string = "1234|Tom|NYC|Student|Active";
let splitValues = string.split("|");
```

Then loop through the array of keys and create an object with the value of the key based on the index of values array:

```
let returnObject = {};

for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    const key = keys[i];
    
    const value = splitValues[i];

    returnObject[key] = value;

};
```

Alternatively, you can create a function that takes the array of keys, the string values, and the delimiter and return the object:

```
function convertDelimitedStringToObject(keys, string, delimiter) {

    let splitValues = string.split(delimiter);

    let returnObject = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        const key = keys[i];

        const value = splitValues[i];

        returnObject[key] = value;

    };

    return returnObject;
};
```

However, this solution will only work if the keys and values always occur in the same order.

If you want it to be a JSON string, you can then call `JSON.stringify()` on the returned object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.split()` like this :

```
let string = "1234|Tom|NYC|Student|Active"
const id = string.split("|")[0]
const name = string.split("|")[1]
```

and then you create you object:

```
const finalObj = {id,name}
```

Comment: hi Thanks, But looking for more dynamic solution instead of taking out strings one by one, as this string value may expand in future with more values.